# Cluster analysis on two columns that contain name of person in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. I have to do cluster analysis in data that contains two columns with name of persons. I converted it in data frame but it is character type. To use dist() function the data frame must be numeric. example of my data:

```
     Interviewed.Type                 interviewed.Relation.Type
1.            An1                           Xuan
2.            An2                           The
3.            An3                           Ngoc
4.            Bui                            Thi
5.            ANT                           feed
7.           Bach                            Thi
8.           Gian1                            Thi
9.           Lan5                            Thi
.
.
.
1100.       Xung                           Van
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you want cluster analysis and not some sort of network analysis?

Comment: Yes..this is my special study part...i have to do cluster analysis, community detection and network analysis too. I am about to finish my network analysis but couldn't do cluster analysis...

Comment: @AlkaShah Can you provide an example of how you want the example data to look?  Converting text to numeric is a substantive decision, and how you do it can dramatically change the meaning of your data and model....

Comment: I have to do cluster analysis but when I use hclust() function it shows error as: > hclust(ajau)
Error in if (n < 2) stop("must have n >= 2 objects to cluster") : 
  argument is of length zero... Here, ajau is my data frame that contains above mentioned data of question...so as a process of cluster analysis, I tried to find dist()..but it give me error that data is not numeric...

Comment: You can convert character to numeric via factor, but as factor indices are pretty much arbitrary, using dist on these will provide little useful information.

Comment: @MvG Thanks a lot. Character to numeric via factor is working well.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your concern...cheers

Comment: OK, if my comment is really what you need, feel free to accept the answer I made from this. I'm still not sure that this is what you want, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a character vector to a factor using `factor`. A factor is basically a vector of numbers together with an attribute giving the text associated with each number, which are called `levels` in R. One can use `as.numeric` or `unclass` to get at the raw numbers. These can then be fed into algorithms which require numbers, like e.g. `dist`.

Note that the order in which numbers are associated with texts is pretty much arbitrary (in fact alphabetical), so the difference between numbers has no meaning in most applications. Therefore calling `dist` on this result is technically possible, but not neccessarily meaningful. For this reason, the author of this answer is not satisfied with it, even if the original poster seems to be happy about it. :-)

Also note that if there are different vectors, converting each separately will mean that the same number will represent different textual values and vice versa, unless both vectors are compromised from exactly the same set of distinct values. Additional care has to be taken if you want the same levels for both factors. One way would be to concatenate both vecotrs, turn that into a factor, and then split the result into two factor vectors.